# How to get rid of shading seams inside a cylinder?

Tags: unity, graphics, blender

Is there any other way to remove these shading "seams" other than to increase the vertex count of the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: How have you created this cylinder? Have you looked up [how to smooth edges in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176062)? What steps have you taken thus far?

Comment: I tried this but it had no effect, and shade smooth effected everything. In a perfect scenario I would be able to smooth out the inner faces only.

Comment: Ive also tried selecting the inside faces and adding smooth modifier, but it creates a pretty wonky effect.

Comment: Sounds like something you might want to post about in more detail on the Blender StackExchange, rather than here. You'll find a higher concentration of Blender experts on that site.

Comment: I am not sure what "seams" you are talking about. That image looks pretty good to me. But it's a JPEG. Perhaps the artifacts are more visible if you post your screenshot as a lossless PNG.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Select *only the faces that you want to smooth*, then select **Face > Shade Smooth**

[image: Shade Smooth]

2. Enable **Shade Smooth** for *all* faces, then enable **Auto-smooth** to only smooth rounded faces (you may need to adjust the Smooth Angle if the default of 30 degrees does not look right for your model)

[image: Auto-smooth]